# Google Apps Script "cannot find function" offset in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can any help with the following issue???  Pretty new to app script / javascript and would appreciate any help or guidance to figure out..

TypeError: Cannot find function offset in object Timestamp, (then continues listing the column headings in the red warning banner.

```
function uiSendLogEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = data.offset(1,0,data.getNumRows())-1;


// For Loop

for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
var row = data[i];
var approved = row[5];
var sentEmail = row[6];
var snapshot = row[3];

//if stmt in For Loop
if ( approved != "Yes" ) {              
  data[i][5] = "Yes";
  data.getDataRange().setValues(data);
      }// if stmt end curly 
else if ( approved == "Yes" && sentEmail != "Yes" ) {
  data[i][6] = "Yes";
  data.getDataRange().setValues(data);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "subject", "body" + "whatever " + snapshot);
}//else if end curly
else {
return;
}//else stmt end curly

}// for loop end curly


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few basic tweaks that will hopefully point you in the right direction (and thanks to @AdamL for the `.shift()` method - much better than what I had in there before :) ):

```
function uiSendLogEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Move the values down
  data.shift();

  // For Loop
  for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    var row = data[i];
    var approved = row[5];
    var sentEmail = row[6];
    var snapshot = row[3];

    // Here we set a range equal to the data range offset by 1 + our current
    // position in the loop (cycling through rows), and then get the A1 notation
    // of the first row, which we use to get that particular range and prep 
    // it for adding values
    var rng = sheet.getDataRange().offset(i+1,0,1).getA1Notation();
    myRange = sheet.getRange(rng);

    //if stmt in For Loop
    if ( approved != "Yes" ) {
      // Here we can just work with the row element itself
      row[5] = "Yes";
      // Because setValues expects a two dimensional array, 
      // we wrap our row in brackets to effectively convert it to one
      myRange.setValues([row]);
    }  // if stmt end curly 
    else if ( approved == "Yes" && sentEmail != "Yes" ) {
      // Same here as above
      row[6] = "Yes";
      myRange.setValues([row]);
      GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "subject", "body" + "whatever " + snapshot);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the revised version.. just tested and seems to be working just fine..  i had forgot i read about shift() before..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to remove the first row of data (the headers); so if that's the case, try replacing:

```
data = data.offset(1,0,data.getNumRows())-1;
```

with

```
data.shift();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, skip the header row.  As I progress I'm sure it will develop.  I'm trying to read in the results of a forum submit, read the spredsheet, determine if the last entry was approved, if not set to approved and then send an email..  Would it be better to just grab the last row and check for it?  the forum will only be submitted a couple times a month now, bu over time it the data will grow...

Comment: If you are only wanting to do your task on each form submission as it arrives, and you have an "on form submit" trigger installed, you can just use the event parameters (see the bottom of https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) - I find that simpler. Please post back if you needed clarification.

Comment: I'll check that out.. That is what I want to get to.. It's basically a workflow, which starts with a forum submit.